# Create user with roles inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create users with roles inside stored procedure. I tried plain query it didn't work, probably because of `GO`, then I tried to put that inside stored procedure, that didn't wok because of `GO` either. I tried to put new line character inside dynamic query, that didn't work either. Can anyone help?

```
create PROCEDURE dbo.CreateUser
AS
BEGIN
/*** Creating User ***/

DECLARE @SQL  NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = '
CREATE USER [PRODUCTION\user1] FOR LOGIN [PRODUCTION\user1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
sp_addrolemember  @rolename =  ''db_owner'', @membername =  ''PRODUCTION\user1''  
GO
CREATE USER [PRODUCTION\user2] FOR LOGIN [PRODUCTION\user2] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
sp_addrolemember  @rolename =  ''db_owner'', @membername =  ''PRODUCTION\user2''  
GO'
/*** Creating User ***/

EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

Comment: `GO` is a SSMS keyword, not a T-SQL Keyword; I suspect if you remove that the error will go away. if you want to use multiple batches, then make multiple calls using `sp_executesql` (I suggest against `EXEC (@SQL)` as, for starters, the query can't be parametrised). Also `sp_addrolemember` is a deprecated function, you should really be using `ALTER ROLE`.

Comment: The thing is it throws an error too without GO

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'sp_addrolemember'.

Comment: You need to end each statement in your dynamic sql with a semicolon. And then you should use exec or execute to call sp_addrolemember.

Comment: use `print @SQL` to see what the final will look like before you try and execute it too.

Comment: I changed that without GO and sp_addrelomember to ALTER ROLE, and that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateUser
AS
BEGIN
/*** Creating User ***/

    DECLARE @SQL  NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = N'CREATE USER [PRODUCTION\user1] FOR LOGIN [PRODUCTION\user1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'CREATE USER [PRODUCTION\user2] FOR LOGIN [PRODUCTION\user2] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];';
    --PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging best friend
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

    SET @SQL = N'ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [PRODUCTION\user1];' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [PRODUCTION\user2];';
    --PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging best friend
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

END
```

This gets rid of the `sp_addrolemember` procedure, which is deprecated. It also splits the creation and memberships into 2 separate batches, to ensure that the users have indeed been created.

Comment: Just a note - the CRLF aids in readability for people but I don't think the SQL Engine cares about it too much assuming that it has some other way to determine statement end (which in your case it does with the semicolon termination). And, pragmatically, I'd parameterize the procedure with `@login` (and possibly `@role`) and change the proc to create the user for that login and add the newly created user to the role. I understand that's not what the OP asked for but makes it more flexible.

Comment: @BenThul the Carriage return and Line break is specifically there for readability. Poorly fornatted dynamic SQL is a nightmare to debug. Although this is a simple example of the statements, I make it a habit to use the same principles with any dynamic SQL I write (which isn't a small amount). Also, you can't parametrised the values as you suggest. You would need to inject the values and **properly quote** them. You can't use syntax `CREATE USER @Login...` it would give a syntax error. The user/login, etc needs to be a literal.